# Count Substring Occurences in MYSQL using Case Statement

Tags: mysql, string, count, substring

I have a string of text that contains multiple substrings within that I'd like to count the occurences of. I saw solutions to a similar question, but I'm wondering if this can be done using a case statement or without creating a new table.

Basically, I'm using a data aggregation/analysis tool that only accepts very basic MySQL statements.

Sample:

```
Paid Search:CLICK, Display:RICH_MEDIA, Display:RICH_MEDIA, Display:RICH_MEDIA, Display:RICH_MEDIA, Display:CLICK, Display:IMPRESSION, Display:IMPRESSION, Display:RICH_MEDIA, Display:RICH_MEDIA, Display:IMPRESSION, Display:CLICK
```

I'd like to extract a count of "Display:Rich_Media"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can accomplish this by the following query:

```
SET @your_string :=
'Paid Search:CLICK, Display:RICH_MEDIA, Display:RICH_MEDIA, Display:RICH_MEDIA, Display:RICH_MEDIA, Display:CLICK, Display:IMPRESSION, Display:IMPRESSION, Display:RICH_MEDIA, Display:RICH_MEDIA, Display:IMPRESSION, Display:CLICK';

SELECT
    ROUND(
        (
            LENGTH(@your_string) - LENGTH(
                REPLACE (
                    @your_string,
                    "Display:RICH_MEDIA",
                    ""
                )
            )
        ) / LENGTH("Display:RICH_MEDIA")
    ) AS totalOccurrence;
```

**Explanation:**

- Length of your string - length after the all the occurerences of the
  subtring replaced by empty
- The result of this subtraction = number of characters you replaced =
  length of your subtring * number of occurrences of the subtring
- Now if you divide the result by the length of the subtring you will
  get the number of occurrences.

Comment: I have multiple strings that contain the same substring of "Display: Rich_Media" but they are not always the same length. Do you have a suggestions for that?

Comment: Show all the possibilities of that string please

Comment: There are potentially endless possibilities of the string. There are 20 "substrings" that make up the full string itself, all separated by commas. There can be one of these substrings up to 50.

Comment: Like you said in your post **I'd like to extract a count of "Display:Rich_Media"**. This query does this. But I didn't get exactly what you meant in your last comment. Please explain a bit more.